# Deleting a row with two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I've created two tables, `simplecomments` and `commentors`, and joined them with `INNER JOIN on commentors.id = simplecomments.commentorid`.

`Commentors` is the personal info of a commenter with following columns: `number(id), name, email..`

`Simplecomments` is details of each and every commenter, containing `comment, reg_date, commentorid, deliverytype, rating...` I've joined them successfully, however I'm finding it hard to delete from the joined table.

I want to make it like this:

if there's last row of a `commentor` called.. let say A, then delete both his comment details and A himself from the table.

Else if A has commented plenty of times, (with different comments), delete his comment details, but let his personal info remain since he, A, has other comments there..

How should I proceed?

Comment: didn't you post this earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238602/deleting-a-row-with-inner-join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a row with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238602/deleting-a-row-with-inner-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a sort of unusual but totally doable request:

check out this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc5e6/1

essentially, a conditional delete should patch you up, assuming you run it after each delete.... which I would personally do so manually but you can also use a [trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_delete.php). Essentially the trigger would run the conditional delete after each delete of a SimpleComment.